# Encerramento de questões

Tags: debate

Me deparei com a seguinte questão onde o usuário estava solicitando ajuda sobre aprendizado: 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183183/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos

Respondi com alguns links sobre apostilas grátis, etc.

Pra minha surpresa veio uma chuva de downvoters, tanto pra questão quanto pra minha resposta.

Pergunto: essa questão não está de acordo com o item "ferramentas comuns entre programadores" contido no na central de ajuda (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

A questão teve 7 downvotes e apenas 3 comentários a respeito da pergunta ser for do escopo. Não seria o caso de darem justificativa ao invés de somente sair dando downvote pelo site?

Comment: Tem um box amarelo com a justificativa, precisa de mais? Sem contar que os comentários lá estão dando uma orientação ao OP, mesmo a pergunta sendo fora do escopo.

Comment: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/91)

Comment: "Pergunto: essa questão não está de acordo com o item "ferramentas comuns entre programadores" contido no na central de ajuda (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?"?

Comment: Não, pedidos/recomendações de softwares, livros etc não são permitidos em perguntas entretanto você pode fazer sugestões de materiais na wiki da tag. Geralmente nesse caso o pessoal indica o link nos comentários.

Comment: [Como podemos lidar com as “listas”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/826/7210)

Comment: Agora sim foram sanadas minhas dúvidas! Valeu @rray!

Comment: Valeu @JorgeB. preciso ler mais o meta!

Comment: Concordo que o número de downvotes foi um tanto excessivo. Mas de qualquer forma, a situação já está sanada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vários comentários na sua pergunta já respondem, porém vou deixar uma resposta também.

**Por que não postar respostas que contenham apenas links?**

Basicamente se os links ficarem fora do ar a resposta será invalidada, isso já é motivo suficiente.

Outro motivo que eu acho válido ressaltar, o site pode perder credibilidade, respostas que o AP precisa sair da página para visualizá-la.

A dica é, caso tenha apenas links use o campo dos comentários.

---

**Por que não pedir opiniões de por onde começar ou apostilas?**

O fato de alguém pedir por onde deve começar a estudar, ou que área seguir é baseado em opiniões, temos diversos usuários, cada um com habilidades diferentes, imagine cada usuário direcionar o AP a uma área diferente? Isso seria ruim, poderia gerar muitas respostas e deixar o perguntador ainda mais em dúvida.

Vincular apostilas seria o mesmo que colocar links, mesmo sendo permitido,e se a apostila for pirata, um pdf digitalizado ou algo do tipo, isso poderia ser fraude, mais uma vez ferindo a reputação do site.

---

**Questão do downvote?**

Não leve downvotes para o lado pessoal, eles estão presentes para ajudar a melhorar a qualidade das perguntas/respostas, geralmente vejo comentários falando o por que do voto negativo (claro que tem algumas exceções).

O ideal é que todos sigam a [central de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help)